# Add searchable fields to Global Search Suggestions

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, search, global-search

The global search bar on can give suggestions based on Name. For example, entering 'X' will a dropdown with X's name on top.

'X''s phone number is 79521075.

I would like to know if it is possible to get the same above suggestion just by entering the phone number or any other custom field. As it stands, if I enter '79521075' in the global search, I will only get the below:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible! Simply make the **Phone** field the second field in the Account object's **Search Results** layout.

This can be done from: Object Settings > Account > Search Layouts > Search Results > Edit

When performing a full search, the results returned are records whose 'Names' or secondary fields (ie. the second field in the Search Results layout) match your search query.

Reference: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=search_instant_results.htm&type=5